# How to display text in system tray icon with win32 api C++ - part 2

Tags: c++, image, winapi, text, system-tray

I have a question similar to this, [How to display text in system tray icon with win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457050/how-to-display-text-in-system-tray-icon-with-win32-api)

I tried his solution but it's not working for me.  I get a small 4x16 white image as the system icon instead of text and I can't understand why.

I'm not using MFC/.NET just win32 api.

```
void UpdateIcon(HWND hWnd){
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    nid.hWnd = hWnd;
    nid.uID = 100;
    nid.hIcon = CreateSmallIcon(hWnd);
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON;
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);
}

HICON CreateSmallIcon( HWND hWnd )
{
    static TCHAR *szText = TEXT ( "100" );
    HDC hdc, hdcMem;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
    HBITMAP hOldBitMap = NULL;
    HBITMAP hBitmapMask = NULL;
    ICONINFO iconInfo;
    HFONT hFont;
    HICON hIcon;

    hdc = GetDC ( hWnd );
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc );
    hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, 16, 16 );
    hBitmapMask = CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, 16, 16 );
    ReleaseDC ( hWnd, hdc );
    hOldBitMap = (HBITMAP) SelectObject ( hdcMem, hBitmap );
    PatBlt ( hdcMem, 0, 0, 16, 16, WHITENESS );

    // Draw percentage
    hFont = CreateFont (12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    TEXT ("Arial"));
    hFont = (HFONT) SelectObject ( hdcMem, hFont );
    TextOut ( hdcMem, 0, 0, szText, lstrlen (szText) );

    SelectObject ( hdc, hOldBitMap );
    hOldBitMap = NULL;

    iconInfo.fIcon = TRUE;
    iconInfo.xHotspot = 0;
    iconInfo.yHotspot = 0;
    iconInfo.hbmMask = hBitmapMask;
    iconInfo.hbmColor = hBitmap;

    hIcon = CreateIconIndirect ( &iconInfo );

    DeleteObject ( SelectObject ( hdcMem, hFont ) );
    DeleteDC ( hdcMem );
    DeleteDC ( hdc );
    DeleteObject ( hBitmap );
    DeleteObject ( hBitmapMask );

    return hIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have windows installed currently so i cannot check if this will work better, but i found potential problem - from MSDN documentation of [CreateIconIndirect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648062%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The application must continue to manage the original bitmaps and delete them when they are no longer necessary.

Seems like you are deleting bitmaps too soon.

Comment: Maybe calling DuplicateIcon(NULL, hIcon), destroying hIcon, and then returning the duplicated icon works. Haven't tried it, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: I would rather recommend - as it was mentioned - simply store somwhere those bitmap and mask until new icon is created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background and possibly foreground colors:

```
SetTextColor( hdcMem, 0x00FF0000 ); // 0x00bbggrr, not rrggbb !!
SetBkMode( hdcMem, TRANSPARENT ); // VERY IMPORTANT
```

I think `DeleteDC ( hdc );` is not needed here as you used `GetDC()`.

Comment: It's not so much that `DeleteDC` is unnecessary, as that `ReleaseDC` should be used instead.

Comment: `ReleasedDC` is actually used on `hdc` (provided by `GetDC`) in @stack356's snippet. `hdcMem` (provided by `CreateCompatibleDC`) is `DeleteDC`'ed. The only problem is the superfluous `DeleteDC(hdc)` here.